# Retrieve then POST a photo to a Foursquare Checkin with Axios

Tags: javascript, foursquare, axios

I'm trying to retrieve, then `POST` a JPEG image to Foursquare's [`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/photos/add) endpoint using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in Node. I've tried a few methods with Axios (and Postman) but always receive the same error response of `Missing file upload`:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "errorType": "other",
    "errorDetail": "Missing file upload",
    "requestId": "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN"  // not the true requestId
  },
  "notifications": [
    {
      "type": "notificationTray",
      "item": {
        "unreadCount": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {}
}
```

The image is created using the Google Static Map API and retrieved with an Axios `GET` request:

```
const image = await axios.get(imageURL, {
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
});
```

which is wrapped in an `async` function and successfully returns a buffer. The data is read into a `Buffer` and converted to a string:

```
const imageData = new Buffer(image, "binary").toString();
```

[Here's an example `imageData` string](https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/20738174e27bcc10222416360140c5ab). I've also tried converting the string to `base64`.

This string is then `POST`ed to the Foursquare endpoint:

```
const postPhoto = await axios.post(
  "https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/photos/add?
    checkinId=1234&
    oauth_token=[TOKEN]&
    v=YYYYMMDD",
  imageData,
  {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" }
  }
);
```

where the `checkinId`, `oauth_token` and `v` params are all valid.

I've tried different `Content-Type` values, `base64` encoding the `imageData` and several other solutions found in forums and here on SO (most are several years old), but nothing works. The response errorDetail always says `Missing file upload`.

The issue could be in how the `POST` request is structured, but I could also be requesting/handling the image data incorrectly. A 2nd (or 3rd, or 4th) set of eyes to check I'm putting this together would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, I have finally solved this.

I was eventually able to get it working thru Postman which provided some hints. Here's the Postman code snippet using `request`:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add',
  qs: 
   { checkinId: [MY CHECKING ID],
     public: '1',
     oauth_token: [MY OAUTH TOKEN],
     v: [MY VERSION] },
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '8ce14473-b457-7f1a-eae2-ba384e99b983',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
  formData: 
   { file: 
      { value: 'fs.createReadStream("testimage.jpg")',
        options: { 
          filename: 'testimage.jpg', 
          contentType: null 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

The key part of this was `fs.createReadStream()`. The part I was missing before was to pass the image as a stream to the request.

Using this I was able to figure out the Axios request:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const querystring = require("qs");
const FormData = require("form-data");

const getImageStream = async function(url) {
  return await axios
    .get(url, {
      responseType: "stream"
    })
    .then(response => response.data);
};

let form = new FormData();
form.append("file", getImageStream([IMAGE URL]));

const requestURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add";
const requestParams = {
  checkinId: [MY CHECKIN ID],
  public: 1,
  oauth_token: [MY OAUTH TOKEN],
  v: [MY VERSION]
};
const requestConfig = {
  headers: form.getHeaders()
};

try {
  const postPhoto = await axios.post(
    requestURL + "?" + querystring.stringify(requestParams),
    form,
    requestConfig
  );

  return postPhoto;
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.response);
}
```

And voila, the request succeeds and the image is posted to the Foursquare checkin.